# Why did the crew of the Covenant NOT want to go to hypersleep?

Tags: plot-explanation, alien-covenant

When the signal from David's planet is discovered in *Alien: Covenant* and the crew is contemplating whether they should go and investigate, it seems like one of the strongest arguments supporting the idea is the possibility of NOT going to hypersleep vs the option of sleeping for over 7 years heading to the original destination.

Why is it? Why do the crew so strongly NOT want to go to hypersleep?

Comment: I wanna say it had to do with the fact the planet was habitable and right there, versus going on for 7 more years.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths Well, at one point, one of the crew members said: "I think it's safe to say that none of us are too keen in getting back into one of these pods". And then the other crew member said: "Wouldn't even have to go back into hypersleep". So it is not like a passing phrase, they specifically focus on this fact in making their decision. And if they went back to sleep, they would not even notice the 7 years sleep, since they would be.. sleeping.

Comment: This movie leaves a lot of questions unanswered.  The planet was there, somehow previously undetected by all-knowing Weyland company and the crew decided to shave off 7 years of the mission.  They already lost colonists and had a damaged ship, figure why waste the opportunity?  I dunno.

Comment: Maybe their confidence in the reliability of the pods is not what it was before they all saw their comrade, Branson, burned to a crisp.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths - Ummm, not discovering every single smaller-than-stellar celestial object in unlimited three-dimensional space is not all that befuddling or mysterious.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet ... but discovered another planet that was another 7 years out?

Comment: @bobbyalex - I'm not sure what you're asking or stating with that sentence fragment, or which of my comments you are responding to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Their original captain (the James Franco character) was burned alive when his sleep pod malfunctioned during the emergency wake-up.  So it's understandable that they'd be skeptical about getting back into the pods.

Comment: That's what I was thinking too.